# Page only shows when user is logged in (even with visibility set to public)

Tags: admin, pages, permissions

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue on a client's site. There is one specific page which appears as "not found" unless you log in and then visit the front end, in which case it appears normally. The visibility on the page is set to public, and in every other way it's a normal boring wordpress page. Stranger still, it only started happening recently (after months of trouble-free use).

Problem page: http://www.leecamp.net/schedule/

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reset your permalinks.  If that doesn't work I'd make sure their isn't another page named schedule in the root directory.

It's possible there is an older (deleted page or post) with the same name stuck in the database as well.  I've experienced this when I deleted a page or post and then created a new one with the same name.

Check the wp-posts table for a conflict.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Did you recently enable a caching plugin? I noticed this was happening after I installed W3 Total Cache. It's just serving up a cached version of the page, so make sure to clear the cache after you publish new content.

Comment: This was my 'problem' - school boy error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check the following: APPEARANCE -> THEMES
"Your site is currently displaying a "Coming Soon" page. Once you are ready to launch your site click here."
CLICK on CLICK HERE.  Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just spend some time "fixing" this. In the end I gave the page a new permalink and it all worked again.

**Some notes:**

- I had two pages that stopped outputting code after the main
  navigation (Wordpress menu, closed the  and then stopped)
- Those pages were not different than other pages of the same post-type
- There were no pages with conflicting names/permalinks found in the
  database
- Pages didn't work when set to "Public" but did with a password
  (didn't need one though top show...)
- Putting the same content (copy/paste) on a new page didn't crash the
  new page

I still have no idea what is going on so the changed permalink is hotfix for now.

If people have some idea I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread, however, maybe some else had the same problem.
In my case it was the slider revolution countdown plugin that caused this issue. Only after deactivating the plugin, the site was loading also in case I was not loged in.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.

Turns out someone had saved the homepage as "Scheduled." I changed it to Published, and it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

DELETE **htaccess file**, is the only 100% working solution.

Comment: Which .htaccess file, the mainWordPress one? Why would that help? This sounds like a caching issue to me.